# Use jQuery to swap/switch between 'div's?

Tags: jquery, html

I was using *[this guide](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/05/replacing-images-at-time-intervals.html)* to sort out some automatic image switching at intervals.

What I'd like to do is adapt it (or get some new ideas) for some images with links which I've currently got as (this is for structural purposes, the `link#` and `image#` variables are actual elements in my code):

```
<div id="myGallery">    
    <div class="active">
        <a href="link1"><img src="image1" /></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="link2"><img src="image2" /></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="link3"><img src="image3" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried changing the bits in the tutorial that referenced `img` to `div`.

The only difference was that the first image took ages to load and none of them were 'clickable' as links.

Comment: use `lowsrc` attribute to improve the performance of ur images, that in mind u need thumbnails of images

Comment: The images are pretty small (240x106px). What do you mean by needing thumbnails of images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, your script:

```
  <script>
    function swapImages(){
      var $active = $('#myGallery .active');
      var $next = ($('#myGallery .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#myGallery .active').next() : $('#myGallery div:first');
      $active.fadeOut(function(){
      $active.removeClass('active');
      $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
      });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      // Run our swapImages() function every 5secs
      setInterval('swapImages()', 2000);
    })
  </script>
```

style :

```
  <style>
    #myGallery{
      position:relative;
      width:400px; /* Set your image width */
      height:300px; /* Set your image height */
    }
    #myGallery div{
      display:none;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
    }
    #myGallery div.active{
      display:block;
    }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    function swapImages(){
      var active = $('.active');


      var next = $(active).next('div');

      if(next.length > 0){

        $(active).removeClass('active');
        $(next).fadeIn().addClass('active');      

        }
        else{
                $(active).removeClass('active');
            next = $('#myGallery div:first-child');
            $(next).addClass('active');      

        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval('swapImages()', 1000);
    })
  </script>
  <style>
    .active{background: red;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myGallery">
  <div class="active">
      <a href="#" >
        <img src="image1.jpg" class="active" />
        LInk 1
        </a>
  </div>



  <div>
   <a href="">LInk 2
    <img src="image2.jpg" />
    </a>
   </div>


    <div>
        <a href="">LInk 3
        <img src="image3.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `$('#myGallery img:first');` with  `$('#myGallery div:first');` which is inside the `swapImages` function

Comment: "I tried changing the bits in the tutorial that referenced `img` to `div`." Already did and that didn't work, unfortunately.